# Proper way to change color scheme for whole application

Tags: colors, smartface.io

Pls give me a hint what is the best way to change color scheme for whole Smartface application: 
1. statically (before building a project)
 2. dynamically (from within running application)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to change the scheme for only one time, you can change it statically. You can define new colors, and change the old ones in the .pge files.

But if you want to change the scheme colors more than once or while you are using the application, you can do this in runtime dynamically. This will be done in script files. Objects properties such as fillColor can be changed in scripts.

I cannot say which one is best but changing in runtime looks better. For example, you can use an editbox to get colors, and then you can use a button, when pressed you can change the color scheme, etc.